# flutter: The getter documents was called on null is shown for a while

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i am calling a method from a stateless widget. This document queries from the firebase database. But when it shows an error in the output for a while and then it shows the result. How can i stop that 3 seconds of error. This is the error shown

> The getter "documents" was called on null.

This is my code.

```
class chats extends StatelessWidget { 
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
child: Container(child:getlast())
}}
```

And this is the meathod

```
getlast(){
    var groupChatId = 123456789;
    var id = chat.UID;
      return FutureBuilder (
        future: Firestore.instance
            .collection("messages")
            .document(groupChatId)
            .collection(groupChatId)
            .orderBy("timestamp", descending: true)
            .limit(1)
            .getDocuments(),
        builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          var con = snapshot.data.documents[0].data["content"];
         Container(
                  height: 27,
                  child: Text("You: $con",
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                      style:  TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20),
                   )});
            }
```

Comment: add return type before getLast function name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `FutureBuilder` you need to check the `connectionState`:

```
          FutureBuilder(
            future: Firestore.instance
            .collection("messages")
            .document(groupChatId)
            .collection(groupChatId)
            .orderBy("timestamp", descending: true)
            .limit(1)
            .getDocuments(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                var con = snapshot.data.documents[0].data["content"];
              Container(
                  height: 27,
                  child: Text("You: $con",
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                      style:  TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20),
                   )});
              } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                return Text("No data");
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
```

`documents` was called on null, means that the data is still not retrieved, therefore by using `connectionState.done` you can then be sure that the data is retrieved.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConnectionState-class.html

Comment: Thanks for your interest but it only returns "No data". although there is data present in the database

Comment: are u sure the path is correct? did you check if the ids are null or not?

Comment: ya i did everything

Comment: remove this `child: Container(child:getlast())` and instead of use `child : FutureBuilder(` and the code in my answer

Comment: I did that. The. Connection state is always waiting

Comment: Can u debug it... Always waiting means its never finishing.. Did u use if(..connectionstate.waiting){ to check if it is always here

Comment: I did it in an alternative way. That’s a lot for your help.